# Android GPS Service Issue

Tags: android, geolocation, gps

I have a service (with a wakelock) that must run continuously behind the scenes capturing user Geo Location. The `Service` implements the `LocationListener` methods (i.e. `onLocationChanged()`).

However it takes some time for `onLocationChanged()` to get invoked by the phone, so in the meantime my service has to do something. I thought of using `Thread.sleep()`, but will that prevent the phone from invoking `onLocationChanged()`? Or should I do polling: while(i < 1000,000) {++i;}?

I'm not getting such abundant GPS results using either of those ideas; wondering if anybody can give me a tip on how to accomplish this.

Comment: can you please upload your code ?

Comment: Well, it's normal for it to take awhile for location (especially first location) after requesting location updates. If your service has to do something else, then just invoke whatever else it needs to do. The service won't be blocked while you're waiting for `onLocationChanged`. But I'm not 100% I understand the entirety of your problem and why you need to call `Thread.sleep()` nor do I know what thread you'd be calling that on.

Comment: I need to do timely GPS recording (e.g. around once every 1min per day and once every 5min per night). But I don't know what to chose from - Thread.sleep(30k) which I think blocks the onLocation() method or busy wait which can drain the battery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by removing WakeLock (waste of battery), doing a 10-second busy wait/Thread Sleep (just in case one blocks the GPS invocation of onLoc()), and using AlarmManager to wake the device from sleep and start the service.

This: gets GPS during sleep AND doesn't drain battery power.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use wait(), and notify() with synchronize block with LocationListener instance.
search for samples using wait(), notify().

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to keep the service "alive" while it is waiting for location changed information. That is taken care of by the system and you do not have to add code for that. When location change information becomes available, the onLocationChanged() would be invoked in the context of your service.